# Diffenence in Settigs of PuppeteerCrawler and Task

Tags: apify

I have migrated a crawler to a Task with legacy-phantomjs-crawler (Task-Version) and, for reasons of efficiency and better design, redeveloped it as a pure Act using PuppeterCrawler (Act-Version). Comparing both versions, it turned out that the Task-Verion about twice as faster than the Act-Verion. I suspect this has something to do with the setup differences, especially according navigation-timeout. But I am not sure.

Why is a scraper as a Task faster than as an Act, with more-or-less the same logic?
What are the setup diffences between an Act with PuppeterCrawler and a Task with legacy-phantomjs-crawler?
How can I setup an Act with PuppeterCrawler, so that I get the same performance as the a Task with legacy-phantomjs-crawler?

Cheers Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this difference is the underlying technology used in these two solutions.

[legacy-phantomjs-crawler](https://apify.com/apify/legacy-phantomjs-crawler) uses [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) as a rendering engine. PhantomJS is very fast, but sadly it's no longer supported by the developers and many websites ban access when PhantomJS is detected. Also it does not support modern javascript ([es6 and later](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)), so some modern websites do not load.

[PuppeteerCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteercrawler) uses chrome/chromium browser controlled through javascript as a rendering engine. This is slower than PhantomJS because there are more processes going on, but modern websites and websites which block PhantomJS usualy work well in it.

There is one more option and that is [CheerioCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/cheeriocrawler) which is even faster than PhantomJS because it does not even render the website and process javascript, it only works with the HTML of the page loaded. This is usualy the best option if the website you want to access does not use javascript to load data and does not have protection against normal network requests.

Sadly in our SDK we do not provide support for PhantomJS anymore, mainly because we were encountering more and more issues with pages blocking it or failing to load. You can speed up the puppeteer crawler, by blocking resources you do not need and waiting for correct events during navigation. [Here](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer#puppeteerblockrequestspage-options-promise) is for example a function which can help you block stuff you do not need to load from the page.